# Fetching only first row from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'tests' where i have tests stored. I have another table called 'test_changes' where i store change log of the tests table. Each time when a test record is changed the test_changes table will get a new row with current timestamp. If a 'tests' record have not been edited before there will be no record for it in the test_change table.

Now am in need of querying the database for all tests and its first ever change record.

```
select * 
from tests 
left join (select MIN(created_on) as created_on, test_id 
           from `test_changes` 
           group by test_id) as tc on tests.id = tc.test_id
```

But it is not fetching MIN values for all the 'tests'... for some test records it is fetching MAX value which is strange. I googled but couldnot able to find a solution which suits my need. can someone tell me what am i missing in the above query ? why it is giving MAX value on some records ?
'created_on' field is UNIXTIMESTAMP data

Comment: What is the type of `created_on`?

Comment: it is unixtimestamp

Comment: MySql has no UNIXTIMESTAMP data  type ( only DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, and YEAR) . Your query looks ok with TIMESTAMP data type.

Comment: It is int(11) field in mysql... the data i store in is UNIX TIMESTAMP which is output of time() PHP function. For some reason am getting MAX instead of MIN data for some records which is strange... !

Comment: Sample `test_changes` data would help. Text please, no images.

Comment: @Joseph . . . Your query should be doing what you want.  Perhaps you are misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
    MIN(created_on) AS created_on,
    test_id
FROM
    test_changes
GROUP BY
    test_id
```

Comment: But my tests table do not have a 'created_on' field. only test_changes table have it...

Comment: Not sure why don't you go with just select min group by. Could you please edit the question showing some test data?